# A problem with adding the ShowcaseView API to gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When i try to add the  [ShowcaseView API](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) to gradle i have an error -

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 23.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection
>   info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries,
>   that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility
>   is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is
>   not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

in a dependencie:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPB15.png)

> "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'"

This is my gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snailp4el.android.tatoeba"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.ichi2.anki:api:1.1.0alpha6'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

}
```

Can you explain me what i do wrong? And how to add the ShowcaseView api to my project. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently had the same problem just minutes ago. It seems that the showcaseview library does not support "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'"

My fix was to downgrade my "compileSdkVersion 28" to "compileSdkVersion 26". You may also need to change all your implementations to 26 instead of 28.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' <== CHANGE TO 26.0.0
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' <== CHANGE TO 26.0.0
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' <== CHANGE TO 26.0.0
```

I believe this will be temporary until the library gets updated to support sdkversion 28 above. Cheerio!